# Automatically save all pages from specific site in Firefox on load

Tags: firefox, browser, web, webpage

I need to go through a list of pages on a specific site so that each page content I visit could be automatically saved with some filename in a specific directory. It's a survey site that only allows step-by-step viewing of these pages so I can't just download them all, I need to do it step by step. Where can I search for some solution for the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Auto Save Document](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2704/) addon which can store the currently shown document in a separate directory automatically when browsing a certain site. It has some limitations. The documents are stored as html-text only (no embedded objects like pictures etc.), and there's 100 pages limit. So I'm not sure if it can meet your needs.

Another addon is [Read It Later](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7661/). It can save pages to a reading list with just one click. It's not full automatic, so you need to click on the small arrow next to the location bar whenever you want to save a page.

Answer (score 0):

[Auto Save HTML](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-save-html/) ([github](https://github.com/nunoarruda/auto-save-html)) will automatically download the HTML document(s) of a specified website when browsing. but based on version 2.0.3 the filename format is fixed and no embedded objects